# From a messy character list to a matrix in R

Tags: r, split, data-conversion

I would really appreciate your help. I have large vector that contains 2000 strings of character of different length, which I retrieved from Web of Science. My dataset can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwrb1f2EpJo_VVJRWldkNVQxZU0/view?usp=sharing).

## Data structure and Outcome.

Each row of this vector has a different "length" but the same pattern. The characters within the "[]" determine the number of rows and the characters outside determine the columns. I will make an example with these three rows:

```
[Sorce, A.; Greco, A.; Magistri, L.] Univ Genoa, Polytech Sch, Thermochem Power Grp TPG DIME, I-16145 Genoa, Italy; [Costamagna, P.] Univ Genoa, Polytech Sch, Thermochem Power Grp TPG DICCA, I-16145 Genoa, Italy
[Allema, Bas; Hemerik, Lia; Rossing, Walter A. H.] Wageningen Univ, NL-6700 AP Wageningen, Netherlands; [Allema, Bas; van Lenteren, Joop C.] Wageningen Univ, Entomol Lab, NL-6700 AP Wageningen, Netherlands; [van der Werf, Wopke] Wageningen Univ, Ctr Crop Syst Anal, Crop & Weed Ecol Grp, NL-6700 AP Wageningen, Netherlands
[Abdissa, Ketema; Tadesse, Mulualem; Bezabih, Mesele; Bekele, Alemayehu; Abebe, Gemeda] Jimma Univ, Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol, Jimma, Ethiopia; [Apers, Ludwig] Inst Trop Med, Dept Clin Sci, B-2000 Antwerp, Belgium; [Rigouts, Leen] Inst Trop Med, Dept Microbiol, Mycobacteriol Unit, B-2000 Antwerp, Belgium
```

The first row has 2 groups in "[]" both with 5 columns each; the second row has 2 groups, one with 3 columns and the second with 4; the third row has 3 groups, with 4, 4 and 5 columns each.

The outcome will be a matrix like this:

```
ID  Author  Info01  Info02  Info03  Info04  Info05
1   Sorce, A    Univ Genoa   Polytech Sch    Thermochem Power Grp TPG DIME   I-16145 Genoa   Italy
1   Greco, A.   Univ Genoa   Polytech Sch    Thermochem Power Grp TPG DIME   I-16145 Genoa   Italy
1   Magistri, L.    Univ Genoa   Polytech Sch    Thermochem Power Grp TPG DIME   I-16145 Genoa   Italy
1   Costamagna, P.  Univ Genoa   Polytech Sch   Thermochem Power Grp TPG DICCA   I-16145 Genoa   Italy
2   Allema  Wageningen Univ  NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A N/A
2   Bas; Hemerik    Wageningen Univ  NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A N/A
2   Lia; Rossing    Wageningen Univ  NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A N/A
2   Walter A. H.    Wageningen Univ  NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A N/A
2   Allema, Bas Wageningen Univ  Entomol Lab     NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A
2   van Lenteren, Joop C.   Wageningen Univ  Entomol Lab     NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands    N/A
2   van der Werf, Wopke Wageningen Univ  Ctr Crop Syst Anal  Crop & Weed Ecol Grp    NL-6700 AP Wageningen   Netherlands
3   Abdissa, Ketema  Jimma Univ  Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol   Jimma   Ethiopia   N/A
3   Tadesse, Mulualem    Jimma Univ  Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol   Jimma   Ethiopia   N/A
3   Bezabih, Mesele  Jimma Univ  Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol   Jimma   Ethiopia   N/A
3   Bekele, Alemayehu    Jimma Univ  Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol   Jimma   Ethiopia   N/A
3   Abebe, Gemeda    Jimma Univ  Dept Med Lab Sci & Pathol   Jimma   Ethiopia   N/A
3   Apers, Ludwig    Inst Trop Med   Dept Clin Sci   B-2000 Antwerp  Belgium    N/A
3   Rigouts, Leen    Inst Trop Med   Dept Microbiol  Mycobacteriol Unit  B-2000 Antwerp  Belgium
```

## My Approach

Separate the strings and convert the vector into a list using this command:

```
CL1 <- str_split(CL, "\\[|\\]", n= Inf)
```

This generates a list of vectors with characters like this:

```
[[1999]]
[1] ""                                                                                               
[2] "Zhuo, Hongying; Li, Qingzhong; Li, Wenzuo; Cheng, Jianbo"                                       
[3] " Yantai Univ, Sch Chem & Chem Engn, Lab Theoret & Computat Chem, Yantai 264005, Peoples R China"

[[2000]]
[1] ""                                                                                                        
[2] "Zuo, Li; Meng, Qing-Hong; Chung, Peter Chee-Keung"                                                       
[3] " Guiyang Med Coll, Dept Immunol, Guiyang 550004, Guizhou Provinc, Peoples R China; "                     
[4] "Yuan, Kai-Tao"                                                                                           
[5] " Sun Yat Sen Univ, Affiliated Hosp 1, Dept Surg, Guangzhou 510080, Guangdong, Peoples R China; "         
[6] "Yu, Li"                                                                                                  
[7] " Guangzhou First Municipal Peoples Hosp, Dept Paediat, Guangzhou 510180, Guangdong, Peoples R China; "   
[8] "Yang, Ding-Hua"                                                                                          
[9] " Southern Med Univ, Nan Fang Hosp, Dept Hepatobiliary Surg, Guangzhou 510515, Guangdong, Peoples R China"
```

As you can see the first element of each vector in the list is blank. Each "even" element of the vectors contains the "groups" and each "odd" element contains the columns of that group.

The next step is to separate the groups to assemble a matrix for this I'm using this two commands.

```
CL2 <- lapply(CL1,function(x)x[2])

AF1 <- lapply(CL1,function(x)x[3])
```

Since in some cases I have more that 50 groups in the same row, basically I have to repeat this process in a loop, but I don't know how, now I'm doing it manually. Another problem is that I don't know how to create an ID and how to merge the lists into a matrix.

Any ideas or suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Dear @AnandaMahto, I'm pretty new both in R and in stackoverflow. My intention was only to point out the error, and also that other users can apply the same technique, when they read this post. I never meant to offend you. But anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks for all your help and understanding, you are awesome, I'll learn more by myself, is just that I'm also in a bit of stress with these project. All my best to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want to achieve:

```
A <- read.csv("AU.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## One vector with all of the data in square brackets
A1 <- regmatches(A[[2]], gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]", A[[2]]))
LA1 <- lengths(A1)

A1 <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", unlist(A1))

## One vector with all of the other data
A2 <- regmatches(A[[2]], gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]", A[[2]]), invert = TRUE)
LA2 <- lengths(A2) - 1

A2 <- unlist(lapply(A2, function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|;\\s+$", "", x[-1])))

## Checking for mistakes....
all.equal(LA1, LA2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(sum(LA1), length(A1))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now that we have the vectors, we can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package to get the output you want:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(magrittr)

## Make a data.table of the two vectors and the ID column
DT <- data.table(ID = rep(A[[1]], LA1), A1, A2)

## Here's the splitting....
final <- DT %>% 
  cSplit("A1", ";", "long") %>%  ## The first column is split and made long
  cSplit("A2", ",")              ## The second column is split and made wide
```

Here's the result:

```
final
#          ID                      A1                                  A2_01                            A2_02
#     1:    1         Aalten, Pauline                Maastricht Univ Med Ctr Sch Mental Hlth & Neurosci MHeNS
#     2:    1 Ramakers, Inez H. G. B.                Maastricht Univ Med Ctr Sch Mental Hlth & Neurosci MHeNS
#     3:    1         Rozendaal, Nico                Maastricht Univ Med Ctr Sch Mental Hlth & Neurosci MHeNS
#     4:    1     Verhey, Frans R. J.                Maastricht Univ Med Ctr Sch Mental Hlth & Neurosci MHeNS
#     5:    1     Biessels, Geert Jan                   Univ Med Ctr Utrecht                      Dept Neurol
#    ---                                                                                                     
# 13949: 2000         Meng, Qing-Hong                       Guiyang Med Coll                     Dept Immunol
# 13950: 2000 Chung, Peter Chee-Keung                       Guiyang Med Coll                     Dept Immunol
# 13951: 2000           Yuan, Kai-Tao                       Sun Yat Sen Univ                Affiliated Hosp 1
# 13952: 2000                  Yu, Li Guangzhou First Municipal Peoples Hosp                     Dept Paediat
# 13953: 2000          Yang, Ding-Hua                      Southern Med Univ                    Nan Fang Hosp
#                          A2_03                 A2_04           A2_05           A2_06 A2_07 A2_08 A2_09 A2_10
#     1:   Alzheimer Ctr Limburg NL-6200 MD Maastricht     Netherlands              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#     2:   Alzheimer Ctr Limburg NL-6200 MD Maastricht     Netherlands              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#     3:   Alzheimer Ctr Limburg NL-6200 MD Maastricht     Netherlands              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#     4:   Alzheimer Ctr Limburg NL-6200 MD Maastricht     Netherlands              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#     5:                 Utrecht           Netherlands              NA              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#    ---                                                                                                      
# 13949:          Guiyang 550004       Guizhou Provinc Peoples R China              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13950:          Guiyang 550004       Guizhou Provinc Peoples R China              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13951:               Dept Surg      Guangzhou 510080       Guangdong Peoples R China    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13952:        Guangzhou 510180             Guangdong Peoples R China              NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13953: Dept Hepatobiliary Surg      Guangzhou 510515       Guangdong Peoples R China    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is great, is working almost perfectly. However, it has a small problem that is critical for me, hope that you can help me. I probably didn't explain myself well, but I need a column of ID, which basically allow me to identify the rows in the "final" matrix, that belong to the same row in the original vector "A". Please let me know if I'm explaining myself well, and if you can help me with that would be great!

Comment: There is a problem in this line "DT <- data.table(ID = rep(A[[1]], LA1), A1, A2))", the warning says "Error: unexpected ')' in "DT <- data.table(ID = rep(A[[1]], LA1), A1, A2))".

Answer (score 0):

You can do some various manipulations with regular expressions, and use `plyr` and `foreach` functions to process everything.  Here is an example of the first row

```
library(foreach)
library(plyr)
str1 = '[Sorce, A.; Greco, A.; Magistri, L.] Univ Genoa, Polytech Sch, Thermochem Power Grp TPG DIME, I-16145 Genoa, Italy; [Costamagna, P.] Univ Genoa, Polytech Sch, Thermochem Power Grp TPG DICCA, I-16145 Genoa, Italy'

##split the string into different parts
s1 = strsplit(str1,'; \\[')
s1. = llply(s1,strsplit,split = ']')[[1]]

##get list of authors
auths = llply(s1.,function(x) gsub('^ ','',strsplit(gsub('\\[','',x[1]),';')[[1]]))
##get all other attributes
other.stuff = llply(s1.,function(x) gsub('^ ','',strsplit(x[2],',')[[1]]))

results = foreach(auth = auths, other = other.stuff, .combine = 'rbind') %do%
 expand.grid(auth,other[1],other[2],other[3],other[4],other[5])
```

The output's column names need to be changed, and you need to iterate this for each line, but that should be easy.

Comment: Dear @user1362215, thanks for your help, I receive some errors in your code. I think because I'm running a different version of R (3.1.2). I first changed " llply " for " sapply ". But now I cannot run the foreach, command. I receive this warning:

install.packages("foreach")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/MarioGS/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘foreach’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘foreach’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
> 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to install two new libraries.

    install.packages(c('foreach','plyr'))

I believe `foreach` comes with `plyr`, but it shouldn't matter.  I meant to use `llply` instead of `lapply`, as it is a `plyr` function.